# How can I replace multiple object values with the values from another object?

Tags: javascript

For example say I've got the following object:

```
person = {firstname:"Freddy", lastname:"Fish", age:15}
```

In this object I would like to replace the first and lastname of the person.

Instead of using

```
person.firstname = "Earthworm";
person.lastname = "Jim";
```

I would like to use something like

```
person += {firstname:"Earthworm", lastname: "Jim"}
```

Comment: possibly you need see about [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: @Stijn: I’m not sure it is a duplicate. That question asked about merging (which kind of implies that the two objects might not have properties with the same name), whereas this question is asking about replacing property values (which implies the objects have identical property names).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The specific example in that question does not ask to replace a value indeed, but the answers seem to cover adding properties and replacing properties.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the answers from here can also help you: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some JavaScript libraries include a method called `extend`, which does what you want:

- jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/
- Underscore: http://underscorejs.org/#extend

You can see Underscore’s implementation here, in case you don’t want to use a library:

- http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-84

And now you can see it here too, no click necessary:

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
        if (source) {
            for (var prop in source) {
                obj[prop] = source[prop];
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to use jQuery for that purpose you can do this:

```
$.extend(person ,{firstname:"Worm", lastname: "Jim"});
```

It will replace the values for the existing fields and add the new ones -> [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

http://jsfiddle.net/9Bfrc/1/

```
person1 = {firstname:"Freddy", lastname:"Fish", age:15};
person2 = {firstname:"errr", lastname:"Fsdfish"};
props=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(person2);
for(i in props){
    var prop=''+props[i];
    Object.defineProperty(person1,prop,{value:person2[prop]});
}
console.log(person1); //Object { firstname="errr", lastname="Fsdfish", age=15}
```